# Cannot build the Spock Example Project using Ant

Tags: maven, groovy, spock

I've just downloaded Spock framework for Groovy and after reading README started to build that without success. There is a problem with downloading some jars.
Have you ever seen something like that, any ideas how to fix it ?

```
~/spock-example-0.5-groovy-1.7$ ant clean test
Buildfile: /home/viking/spock-example-0.5-groovy-1.7/build.xml

clean:

bootstrap.maven.tasks:
      [get] Getting: http://www.apache.org/dist/maven/binaries/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar
      [get] To: /home/viking/spock-example-0.5-groovy-1.7/ant/lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.apache.org/dist/maven/binaries/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.apache.org/dist/maven/binaries/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.apache.org/dist/maven/binaries/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar
      [get] Can't get http://www.apache.org/dist/maven/binaries/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar to /home/viking/spock-example-0.5-groovy-1.7/ant/lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar

BUILD FAILED
/home/viking/spock-example-0.5-groovy-1.7/build.xml:14: Can't get http://www.apache.org/dist/maven/binaries/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar to /home/viking/spock-example-0.5-groovy-1.7/ant/lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: Out of interest, why are you trying to build what looks like Spock 0.5 for Groovy 1.7? Also, where did you download it from?

Comment: It looks like you get it from SVN on Google Code which is abandoned. Get the version from Git https://github.com/spockframework/spock/. Make a note that there is not master branch in Spock. The is the main branch groovy-1.8 (for Groovy 1.8) and groovy-1.9 (for Groovy 2.x) where changes from groovy-1.8 are merged into. You should (probably) use branch groovy-1.8. See this doc: https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/groovy-1.8/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: The [spock-example](http://github.spockframework.org/spock-example) project on GitHub only has a master branch. The Ant builds for older versions of spock-example won't work anymore because for whatever reason, http://www.apache.org/dist/maven/binaries keeps removing older versions of `maven-ant-tasks`.